# My Program for testing model to a video doesnt show anything

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

currently i am learning deep learning
last week i try to run my program and its work fine but now nothing show up when the log are same

it doesnt show up after i reinstall my nvidia driver

i already install cuda and cuddn for tensorflow just like what at tensorflow documentation said

here are the code that i have

```
# import miscellaneous modules
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
import time
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
# import keras_retinanet
from tensorflow.keras import models
import sys

model_path = 'Model/CCTV_10Frame_SGD_Model_1e4_b16_l21e2_224_Terbaru.h5'
model = models.load_model(model_path)

vid = cv2.VideoCapture("Data Fix/Data16_116.mp4")

while(vid.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    vid.set(3, 480)
    vid.set(4, 240)
    start = time.time()
    if ret == True:
        draw = frame.copy()
        draw = cv2.cvtColor(draw, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        scale_percent = 20 # percent of original size
        width = 224
        height = width
        dim = (width, height)
        frame_set = cv2.resize(draw, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        frame_set=np.arange(10*width*height*3).reshape(10,width, height, 3)
        frame_set.reshape(10, width, height, 3).shape
        frame_set = np.expand_dims(frame_set, axis=0)
        result=model.predict_on_batch(frame_set)
        # Get the predicted class from the result using argmax
        pred_class = np.argmax(result)
        # Here I assume that the index is the desired class like most cases

        # Now we will write the class label on the image
        # Set the font and place
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        org = (50, 50)
        cv2.putText(draw, str(pred_class), org, font, .5, (255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

        # now just show the frame
        cv2.imshow('frame', draw)

        print(result)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break


vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the log are like this

```
2021-08-30 23:18:53.846817: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-08-30 23:19:24.046369: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll2021-08-30 23:19:24.671644: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:03:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce 920MX computeCapability: 5.0
coreClock: 0.993GHz coreCount: 2 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 13.41GiB/s
2021-08-30 23:19:24.672060: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-08-30 23:19:24.687853: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-08-30 23:19:24.688315: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-08-30 23:19:24.709928: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-08-30 23:19:24.714666: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-08-30 23:19:24.720694: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_11.dll
2021-08-30 23:19:24.728896: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-08-30 23:19:24.730655: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_8.dll
2021-08-30 23:19:24.731295: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-08-30 23:19:24.732060: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-08-30 23:19:24.733284: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:03:00.0 name: NVIDIA GeForce 920MX computeCapability: 5.0
coreClock: 0.993GHz coreCount: 2 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 13.41GiB/s
2021-08-30 23:19:24.734279: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-08-30 23:19:25.486129: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1258] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-08-30 23:19:25.486614: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1264]      0 
2021-08-30 23:19:25.486863: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1277] 0:   N
2021-08-30 23:19:25.487580: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1418] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1363 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce 920MX, pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
```

nothing error show up but the cv2.imshow didnt work, i try to add some print before the cv2.imshow too for testing but no result for print too

any answer would be helpfull

thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your video file into your project folder, change

```
vid = cv2.VideoCapture("Data Fix/Data16_116.mp4")
```

as

```
vid = cv2.VideoCapture("Data16_116.mp4")
```

You can try adding this code if your video is opened or not, add this under vid = cv2.... line

```
if (vid.isOpened()== False):
   print("error")
```

Comment: if i did, it'll make error since the model need 4 dimension for the timeDistributed for cnn+lstm

Comment: I see, I guess the problem is on model or video, I tried your code using another model and video and it worked, there is nothing wrong in your code. Did you try another video?

Comment: i did, its still the same and it doesnt show anything nor error anything, thank you for trying the code, it happen after i reinstall my nvidia driver, but idk what am i missing, i install everything just like what tensorflow documentation ask:(

Comment: You don't get any error and this is the weird part. I guess you have a notebook and you don't need to install CUDA or CUDNN, your graphic driver will be enough for this. Maybe you can try to run it without CUDA.

Comment: You don't have to but you should try :) I suggest you to try without CUDA, maybe the problem is this.

Comment: already try it still have the same problem, i'll try to reinstall my nvidia driver again maybe it might work, i hope

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236784/discussion-between-acemi-and-juniorpython).